# Short story about the Dalai Lama: the next incarnation picks the short path

Tags: story-identification, religion

I am looking for a short story about the Dalai Lama. The next incarnation is force-grown and he picks the short path.

In choosing the short path, his Holiness's behaviors are the antithesis of what we expect.  Various political entities through the Buddhist culture vie for the Lama's attention. At the end of the story,

> the traitor who bent him to the short path is found and put into a pain synthesizer that will keep her alive for eternity.

I know this appeared in one of the best scifi anthologies, but I cannot find it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's ["Prayers on the Wind"](http://www.walterjonwilliams.net/2011/10/prayers-on-the-wind/) by Walter Jon Williams, which appeared in [The Year's Best Science Fiction: Ninth Annual Collection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Year's_Best_Science_Fiction:_Ninth_Annual_Collection), edited by Gardner Dozois. A new Incarnation of the Gyalpo Rinpoche (the Dalai Lama) is identified via reincarnation-tracking technology, artificially caused to grow from a fetus to an adult very quickly, and when he emerges he declares "Short Path" (a term from Tantric Buddhism) and does all manner of shocking things, for reasons revealed later in the story.